# If we used or if we have used

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, conditional-constructions, past-simple

I'm wondering which one of these two sentences is correct? And if they both are correct, then what's the difference between them?

- For displacement maps we use 32 bit depth images in order to avoid
  render artifacts which might occur if **we used** lower bit depth
  instead.
- For displacement maps we use 32 bit depth images in order to avoid
  render artifacts which might occur if **we have used** lower bit depth
  instead.

Comment: If you're going to use a Perfect form (my advice being *not* to), it would have to be *...which might occur if we **had** used [blah blah]*. Or more properly, *...which might **have occurred** if we **had** used [blah blah]* (which I hope shows why you should avoid Perfect forms unless you ***need*** them! :)

Comment: ...strictly speaking you should probably use a subjunctive for the "irrealis, counterfactual" possibility: *which might occur if we **were to use / were to have used** [blah blah]*. But I'd suggest you just keep it simple with *...which might occur **with** lower bit depth* (forget the superfluous word ***instead***).

Comment: So the present perfect in not applicable here. I'm wondering how the meaning would change with the past perfect _which might_ **have occurred** _if we_ **had used**. Can you provide an elaborate answer in the answer section and will accept it as the best. Thanks.

Comment: *Present* Perfect is completely wrong for your context. It's okay in something like ***If I have offended you** then I apologize*, where the speaker ***doesn't know*** whether the situation being referred to occurred or not. But in your context the speaker knows for sure that they ***didn't*** use lower bit depth. So the reference is one of [***irrealis***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood), and I've just discovered from that Wikipedia link that ***Every language has a formula for the "unreal"***, so hopefully that makes sense to you.